# CDT interaction with GDB Client

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

We know that CDT interact with gdb client which in turn interacts with gdb server while debugging. I wanted to know how really CDT interacts with gdb client or any reading material will do just fine I ain't able find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse CDT uses [GDB/MI Interface](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html) for interacting with gdb. See in [GDB Wiki](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends):

```
1.1. Using modern GDB/MI
...
...
...
Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling) - The CDT Project provides a fully functional C and C++ Integrated Development Environment based on the Eclipse platform.
```